# Missing OAuth grant rate graph in OAuth Consent Screen dashboard of Google Cloud project

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, oauth, oauth-2.0

I cannot seem to see any information in the "OAuth grant limits" graph I expect to find in the OAuth consent screen settings at https://console.cloud.google.com > (project) > (hamburger menu) > APIs & Services > OAuth consent screen settings panel.  This is what I see:

[image]

Why is there "No data for this time interval"?  This is true both in my dev project and in my prod project, which has tens of thousands of users using OAuth.

Does this graph not show any information for mobile application token grants (Android specifically)?

Can one monitor how close one is to breeching the OAuth grant limit somehow differently?  As far as I can tell, this is the only place that Google reports it.

Answer (score 1):

If your project is only requesting access to the identity scopes (openid, email or profile), then [the token grant rate limit won't be checked](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/client-verification#applicability).

This is occurring because those identity scopes are not sensitive scopes. I am also assuming that your application is verified, since you mentioned having a large userbase.

Verified apps also [don't have a user cap](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/client-verification#requesting_verification).

Comment: Our app only uses the "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata" [View and manage its own configuration data in your Google Drive.] and "email" scopes.  Neither of these scopes are sensitive and our app is not verified.  Would this mean we aren't subject to a user cap?  Am I reading your answer correctly?